# Common lisp hashtable

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable

Task is to read N string like "name phone" and store in. Then find stored data with requests like "name".
My code stores names and numbers in hashtable, but after it doesn't find any values. Stored values checks with maphash (it shows all pairs key-value).

Function split-by-one-space is just utility.

```
(defparameter data (make-hash-table))

(defun split-by-one-space (string) ; to split string: "aaa bbb" -> (aaa bbb)
    (loop for i = 0 then (1+ j)
          as j = (position #\Space string :start i)
          collect (subseq string i j)
          while j))

(dotimes (i (read)) ; input data
    (let* ((inp (read-line))
           (raw (split-by-one-space inp))
           (name (string (car raw)))
           (phone (cadr raw)))
         (format t "Adding: ~W ~W~%" name phone) ; debug
         (setf (gethash name data) phone)))
(maphash #'(lambda (k v) (format t "~a => ~a~%" k v)) data) ; this show all stored data
(loop for line = (read-line *standard-input* nil :eof)
      until (or (eq line :eof) (eq line nil))
      do
      (let ((key (gethash line data))) ; it cannot find anything. Why?
           (format t "Searching: ~W~%" line) ; debug
           (if (null key)
               (format t "Not found~%")
               (format t "~A=~A~%" (car key) (cdr key)))))
```

Sample input:

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

Comment: See [Using string object as a hash key in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1409069/5747548)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you specify a test function, hash tables will use `eql` to determine "is this key identical to that key".

```
(defvar *s1* "a string")
(defvar *s2* "a string")
(loop for pred in '(eq eql equal equalp)
  do (format t "Using ~a, the result is ~a~%"
     pred (funcall pred *s1* *s2*)))
```

This generates the output:

```
Using EQ, the result is NIL
Using EQL, the result is NIL
Using EQUAL, the result is T
Using EQUALP, the result is T
```

In this case, the main difference between `equal` and `equalp` is that the latter is case-insensitive, while the former is not. To use another test function, use the `:test` keyword and one of the found "standard" test functions. If you don't need case-insensitive matches, you would simply create your hash table like this: `(make-hash-table :test #'equal)`.

Comment: @coredump Bah, I was hoping that "block quoting" would preserve line endings and foolishly didn't check. Thanks for the edit.